# How to implement a Forward Selection using KNN?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn, feature-selection

I am trying to use a wrapper method in Python to implement a simple forward selection using KNN from the data I have.

My data:

```
ID     S_LENGTH     S_WIDTH     P_LENGTH     P_WIDTH     SPECIES
------------------------------------------------------------------
1      3.5          2.5          5.6         1.7        VIRGINICA
2      4.5          5.6          3.4         8.7         SETOSA
```

This is where I have defined `X` and `y`:

```
X = df[['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH', 'P_LENGTH', 'P_WIDTH']].values
y = df['SPECIES'].values
```

This is a simple KNN model:

```
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(X_fs,y)
predictions = clf.predict(X_fs)
metrics.accuracy_score(y, predictions)
```

Therefore, how would I implement a KNN model using forward selection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do [not believe that KNN has a features importance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363662/can-you-derive-variable-importance-from-a-nearest-neighbor-algorithm) built-in, so you have basically three options. First, you can use a model agnostic version of feature importance like permutation importance.

Second, you can try adding one feature at a time at each step, and pick the model that most increases performance.

Third (closely related to second), just try every permutation! Since you only have 4 features, assuming you don't have too much data, you could just try all combinations of features. There are 4 models of one feature, 6 (4 choose 2) models with two features, 4 with three, and 1 with all four. That's probably less computation than the above two ideas.

So something like this:

```
feat_lists = [
    ['S_LENGTH'], 
    ['S_WIDTH'],
    ...
    ['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH', 'P_LENGTH'],
    ['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH', 'P_WIDTH'],
    ...
    ['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH', 'P_LENGTH', 'P_WIDTH']
]

for feats in feat_lists:
    X = df[feats].values
    y = df['SPECIES'].values

    ...all you other code...
    print(feats)
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(y, predictions))
```

To clarify, I'm assuming that's not actually your data, but only the first two rows, correct? If you only have two rows, you have bigger problems :)

Comment: Also, you should split this data into train and test, and modify your code to measure the accuracy based on the test set (which isn't used in the `fit` line).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this. This makes more sense. Though, say if I had over 20 columns, what would the best approach be instead of a permutation?

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah so "permutation importance" (not the same as trying all the permutations of features) is a way to rank order the importance of each feature in a model. So you'd run one big model with all feats, then use permutation importance to find which feature is the least important, then remove it, then repeat. Technically this is backwards stepwise, not forward

Comment: If you really want to do forward, that's more like option 2 in my answer. Start with 20 models, each with one feature. Take the best model and "lock in" that feature. Then run 19 models with that feature plus each of the other ones. Pick the best so that you've 'locked in' 2 feats. And repeat until no feature adds any performance.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information and support you have provided today. I appreciate this very much.